# I created a mail server using postfix and dovecot on ubuntu 20.04 but my mail goes to spam

Tags: 20.04, postfix, mail, dovecot

I created a mail server using postfix and dovecot on ubuntu 20.04. I'm using a valid trusted SSL certificate from let's encrypt, but my mail goes to spam on Gmail and other mail services. I'm sending the email's with port 587 so what's my problem?

Comment: I'd start here: https://www.mail-tester.com/ That's what I use to check the boxes.

Comment: Also, this question isn't really all that specific to Ubuntu.